# The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. error with paypal express gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have used gem 'paypal-express' for connecting paypal from rails 4 application.

I have added to

```
item = {
                               name: self.title,
                               description: self.title,
                               quantity: self.quantity,
                               item_number: self.item_number,
                               amount: self.amount
                           }
```

as a payment request.. For multiple number of items it is always showing the following error.. 
**The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts**

I have rounded off the value to 2 decimal places.. But it still shows error ...
Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: there are lots of answers like this on stackoverflow, sure none of them helps you debugging this issue?

Comment: were you ever able to get this gem working?

Comment: @pwz2000: No, this gem is not working on my way..